# Assigning variables at runtime with pre-determined objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following objects:

```
var myObj = 
{ 
    prop1 : 'val', 
    prop2 : 'val'
},

hisObj = 
{ 
    prop1 : 'val',
    prop2 : 'val'
},

herObj = 
{ 
    prop1 : 'val',
    prop2 : 'val'
};
```

Now I run an ajax call and return 3 sets of data as arrays. The key of each of these arrays is equal to: `my`, `his` and `her`.

How would I assign the correct object to a private variable within a function that deals with the ajax response. I tried this to start:

```
function ajax_callback(data)
{
    $.each( data, function( key , value )
    {
        var options = key + 'Obj';

        ...
    });
};
```

`var options` in this case is rightly of type `string`. How would I have dynamically created the variable `options` to contain the correct object rather than a string representation of it's name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not sure what you are trying to achieve here. But you probably need to "namespace" your objects inside another object. How about:

```
var obj = {
    her: {
        prop1: 'val',
        prop2: 'val'
    },
    his: {
        prop1: 'val',
        prop2: 'val'
    }
/// etc

function ajax_callback(data) {
    $.extend( obj, data ); // merge the data with the previously defined object
});
```

Or if you want to pluck an entry from the object based on your response key:

```
function ajax_callback(data) {
    $.each( obj, function( key, val {
        var options = obj[key];
    });
});
```

Comment: The `his`, `her`, and `my` analogies don't work so well at giving any idea at what I was trying to achieve. Essentially I was writing a catch all function for all my ajax calls. Rather than hardcoding the options objects for specific calls I was trying to find a way to dynamically assign them based on the repsonse JSON's key.

Comment: Meant to add to the above, I'll give this a shot, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

Put your variables into an object and then use the key as the index:

```
var parentObj = 
    myObj: { 
        prop1 : 'val', 
        prop2 : 'val'
    },
    hisObj: { 
        prop1 : 'val',
        prop2 : 'val'
    },
    herObj: { 
        prop1 : 'val',
        prop2 : 'val'
    }
};

function ajax_callback(data) {
    $.each( data, function( key , value ) {
        var options = parentObj[key];
        ...
    }
}
```